# Confuse using ADT 20

Tags: android

Can I use API 10 in ADT 20 ? When I created a new project, I always get, if I choose `targetSdk` under API 15. (different from when I used ADT 18 last week)

I want to create a simple "hello world" project that will run on `Gingerbread`. with ADT 20, eclipse forces me to create a new project using API 15 or higher. How can I solve this problem?

I am using eclipse indigo, Latest SDK and ADT 20.

I am getting errosr in my MainActivity:

```
getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
```

case android.R.id.home:

I get an Error in `getActionBar()`...
and case android.R.id.Home

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> can I use API 10 in ADT 20 ?

Yes you can.

> when i created a new project, i always look errors at the project if i
>   choose build sdk under API 15.

```
getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

That's because you are using an ActionBar. You can't use an ActionBar in API 13<. You won't get Errors if you set the `buildtarget` to API 15, because then the project will be created as if it would run on ICS. But it it would eventually crash in APIs lower than 13. If you want to create an ActionBar for lower APIs I recommend you using [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/).

Comment: how can i set for the first time ? (note : when i am buliding a new project like this tutorial:http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/creating-project.html i always getting error after build. the error like above)

Comment: what do you choose as your buildtarget and minimumsdk versions?

Comment: i choose Android 2.3.3 (API 10) in buildtarget and minimumsdk Android 2.2 (Froyo API 8)

Comment: You can't choose a Buildtarget lower than 13 if you are going to use an ActionBar. You have to go with an alternate ActionBar then

Answer (score 0):

Well you don't need  to getActionbar for simple hello message . use this function which you are following by android tutorial.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
//  setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message);
//  getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
    TextView textView = new TextView(this);
    textView.setTextSize(40);
    textView.setText(message);
    setContentView(textView);
}
```